# Let $f,g$ be $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable functions. I want to show piecewise function $h$ of $f$ and $g$ is also measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f,g$ be $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable functions. I want to show piecewise function $h$ of $f$ and $g$ is also measurable.

Suppose $(X, \mathcal E)$ is a measure space, let $f,g$ be $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable functions and let $A \in \mathcal E$.

I want to show $h: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $ h(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       f(x)  : x \in A\\
       g(x) : x \in A^C
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$ is again a $\mathcal E$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable function.

I've tried writing $(-\infty, a]$ as two disjoint sets $A_1, A_2$ such that $A_1 \cup A_2 = (-\infty, a]$, but then $f^{-1}(-\infty, a]) = f^{-1}(A_1 \cup A_2) = f^{-1}(A_1) \cup f^{-1}(A_2)$ and I can't say whether this is an element of $\mathcal E$. Also I don't use that $A \in \mathcal E$.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can I just check your notation; you mean f and g are measurable functions from (X, E) to (R,Borel)?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 3):

For any Borel set $B$ one has
$$
h^{-1}(B)=\big(f^{-1}(B)\cap A\big)\cup \big(g^{-1}(B)\cap A^c\big).
$$

Comment: Ahh, and now the result follow easily by means of every intersection and union lies in $\mathcal E$. Thanks !

Comment: Yep. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that multiplication and addition of measurable functions are again measurable? If yes, simply note that

$$
h = f \cdot \chi_A + g \cdot \chi_{A^c},
$$

where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$.